# How to pass confluence page body content in confluence user macro

Tags: confluence-macros

How to pass Confluence page body content in a Confluence user macro once a user clicks on a certain icon in the view page screen?

I have a requirement where I am adding a button on the Confluence view page beside the edit page option. I want to call an external API and pass the current page body content as the API body.

Can anyone provide any pointers on how I can do that?

I am trying to call the Confluence get content API to retrieve the page body content, but I want to check if there is any built-in method for a Confluence user macro to fetch the current page body content?